# Transparently compress attributes before storing in database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, compression

One of my models has a huge text column that I'd like to compress before storing it in the database (not to save disk space, but because I don't want to have to send the uncompressed field over the wire from my DB server to my app server)

My database is postgresql if that's relevant

Here's the extension I tried writing, but for some reason this isn't working in production (the data actually getting stored in the database looks like hex (e.g. "34bee1c2d099ba21da3ac533d5f99cda2654feb73985430df39c5ffd8fbf9d9ff3aa9392d5a5" instead of Zlib output (e.g. "A\xEB\xD3\xF2Oy=\x9C\x7F5\xE9\xC44\x01M\"). Not sure what's going on

```
module HasCompressedAttributes
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_compressed_attributes(*fields)
      fields.each do |field|
        define_method(:"#{field}=") do |uncompressed|
          write_attribute(:"#{field}", Zlib::Deflate.deflate(uncompressed))
        end

        define_method(:"#{field}") do
          Zlib::Inflate.inflate(read_attribute(:"#{field}")) rescue nil
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval{ include HasCompressedAttributes }
```

Is there a better approach here? Maybe an existing gem?

Answer (score 1):

The default encoding method for `bytea` in recent versions of PostgreSQL is ["hex"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html):

> The "hex" format encodes binary data as 2 hexadecimal digits per byte, most significant nibble first. The entire string is preceded by the sequence \x (to distinguish it from the escape format).

So the `34bee1c2d099ba21da3ac...` stuff you're seeing in the database is just hex encoded binary data. AR should be encoding and decoding that stuff for you if you're using a `bytea` column (i.e. [`t.binary`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types) when creating the column) rather than a `text` or `varchar` (i.e. `t.text` or `t.string`). If you're going to store binary data in the database then you have to use `t.binary` so you can't completely hide this magic inside a module, the schema has to be correctly set up as well.

Comment: I am using a `bytea` column, but the encoding is still wrong (I'm using the exact same database in Prod and Dev, and it works in Dev but not in Prod, oddly enough)

Comment: @Horace: Do you have different PostgreSQL versions in dev and production?

Comment: @Horace: That's not enough of a difference, do the have the same [`bytea_output`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT) setting?